# Upgrade MS Sync Framework 2.0 to 2.1 with SQL Server 2008 change tracking

Tags: sql-server-2008, microsoft-sync-framework, change-tracking

I'm using Sync Framework 2.0 with SQL Server 2008 and Sql Compact Server 3.5 SP and use the integrated SQL Server change tracking.

Now I want to upgrade the Sync Framework to version 2.1

Help says there is an 2.0 compatibility mode and that CE databases upgraded automaticaly. 
When I connect to an CE database I last synchronized with the 2.0 version I get the message:

`Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.DbNotProvisionedException The current operation could not be   completed because the database is not provisioned for sync or you not have permissions to the sync configuration tables. Boolean NeedsUpgrade()`

As it seems Sync Framework tries to upgrade the database using the wrong change tracking mechanism.
But I wasn't able to find a way to set the mechanism to use.

> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:720, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:722, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:726, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:728, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:729, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer;Password=****
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:737, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:757, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:770, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:810, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:834, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:846, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:851, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:862, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:883, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:894, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:925, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:931, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:937, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:947, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:952, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:961, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:966, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:975, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:985, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:25:990, Connecting using string: Data Source=mueller1103;Initial Catalog=Customer.Web;User ID=Customer
>
> VERBOSE, w3wp, 17, 08/30/2011 11:54:26:000, Connecting to database: D:\Customer\Customer.WEB\Service\App_Data\1a074cdb-b03a-406a-8996-098811c375a2CustomerMobil.sdf
>
> System.NullReferenceException object reference not set to an instance of an object. Boolean UpgradePublicTracking(System.String)
>   at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeChangeTracking.UpgradePublicTracking(String connectionString)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeClientSyncProvider.PerformUpgradeIfNecessary()
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeClientSyncProvider.BeginTransaction(SyncSession syncSession)
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncAgent.DataSynchronize()
>   at Microsoft.Synchronization.SyncAgent.Synchronize()
>   at Customer.Sync.Mobile.MobilSync.SyncUp() in D:\Customer\Customer.Sync\Customer.Sync\Mobile\MobilSync.cs:Zeile 38.
>   at Customer.WEB.Communication.Sync.DoSyncThread(Object syncParams) in D:\Customer\Customer.WEB\MobilSync\Sync.cs:Zeile 79.

Answer (score 0):

am assuming you're trying to migrate your SqlCeClientSyncProvider/DBServerSyncProvider/SyncAgent synchronization to the SqlSyncProvider/SqlCeSyncProvider/SyncOrchestrator.

the former is referred to as the offline providers (used also by the Local Database Cache project item in Visual Studio) which works on a hub-spoke topology. the latter is referred to as collaboration providers which can work in either hub-spoke or peer-to-peer scenarios.

These providers are different in the way they track and apply changes and in the way they keep the synchronization metadata so you cant really "upgrade" the provider but rather "migrate" to another set of provider.

if you migrate to the new providers, you will have to provision the database using the provisioning API.

here's an end to end tutorial for using the new providers:

[Tutorial: Synchronizing SQL Server and SQL Server Compact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff928494%28v=SQL.110%29.aspx)

moreover, you can retain you're existing code in 2.0 and run them as it is in 2.1 as there is not much that has changed in the providers you're using.

Comment: At the moment I use the SyncAgent with SyncAdapters to filter tables.
Is there the need to migrate to another provider? Because it would be a lot of work to change the SyncAdapters filters for SyncOrchestrator.

Comment: as i have mentioned, the syncagent uses a different set of providers than that of the syncorchestrator. so you cant reuse the same adapters. if you're not changing providers, your code should run as it is even if you upgrade the framework to 2.1. and there is not much for you to gain since not much has changed in the providers youre using from 2.0 to 2.1

Comment: The problem is that I haven't changed anything at the classes. I just changed the reference from sync fx2.0 to fx2.1  and get this exception.

Comment: check that you are running sql compact 3.5 sp2

Comment: I checked that sql compact 3.5 sp2 is on the system (x86 and x64) and is used but as it seems not to have any effect

Comment: can you enable sync framework tracing and post the trace where the exception gets raised?

Comment: as you see the problem is at the beginning when opening the database, and the problem seams to be the a null value for UpgradePublicTracking. But I can't find what I need to set for this value

Comment: the UpgradePublicTracking string parameter is actually a connection string. inside that call its throwing an ArgumentNullException if connection string is null. am not sure where the NullReferenceException  is coming from though. the code has actually establish and opened a connection to the database prior to hitting UpgradePublicTracking, so connection string must have a value. the code inside UpgradePublicTracking has a try catch as well so exception inside should not have bubbled up.